# alert with mootools and joomla

Tags: joomla, mootools

I have to try something very simple with mootools and joomla 2.5, but dont work.

I only can show a alert when I clicking in a link of my menu

I only want to show a alert,firebug don´t reconized any error but don´t show the alert to.

```
 window.addEvent('domready', function() {
            var opt = {
                slides: 'sliders',
                duration: 1500,
                auto: true,
                delay: 5000,
                buttons: {next:'go-prev', prev:'go-next'},
                transition: Fx.Transitions.Quint.easeOut
            }
            var scroller = new QScroller('carrusel', opt);
            scroller.load();

          $$('.item-1 a').addEvent('click', function(event){
                alert('clicked!');
            });

        });
        </script>

<ul class="menu">
<li class="item-1">
<a href="/index.php/descripcion">Click here!</a></li>

</ul>
```

the solution

```
window.addEvent('domready', function() {
$$('.item-1 a').addEvent('click', function(event){
                alert('clicked!');
            });

            var opt = {
                slides: 'sliders',
                duration: 1500,
                auto: true,
                delay: 5000,
                buttons: {next:'go-prev', prev:'go-next'},
                transition: Fx.Transitions.Quint.easeOut
            }
            var scroller = new QScroller('carrusel', opt);
            scroller.load();



        });
        </script>
```

Comment: try adding the class `item-1` to `<a>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has syntex error try this-

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Lt8Gg/1/)

```
window.addEvent('domready', function(event) {
 $$('.item-1').addEvent('click', function(event){
                    alert('clicked!');
     event.stop();
 });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$$('a').addEvent('click', function(event){
    event.stop();
    alert('clicked!');
});​
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Sh7yQ/2/)

try the above code and let me know

Comment: Hi @Dasun, thanks  you help me to found the solution. I modified the question to explain better.  I have the code in my index, but if I move to other file , for example inside of component don´t work